# Implementing a provider for data on the App startup

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, riverpod

i am building an app with firebaseauth and firebasestore. On the startup I am storing a constant value of the current user. From the uid it takes the id and gets the object out of the firebasestore database for more user data.

```
CustomUserData.withData({
required this.uid,
required this.firstname,
required this.lastname,
required this.birthday,
required this.shortname,
required this.rawData,
required this.isPassive,
required this.lastLogin,
required this.role,
required this.buildNumber,
```

This my CustomuserData class.

Now I want to store this object as a provider from riverpod. But I don't know how to set this value on the startup to listens in the whole app after ist.
Currently I am always accessing my static variable.

Do you know any working solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Simply wrap your MaterialApp or whatever your top level widget is with the provider.

```
class DBViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  const DBViewer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ProController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TableController()),
      ],
      builder: (context, _) {
        Provider.of<ProController>(context, listen: false).init();
        return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: dbService.darkModeListenable,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return MaterialApp(
```

My app is using providers from provider package, but should be same for riverpod as well.

Comment: How is your constructor looking in the ProController ? After the app and the authuser is loaded I need to get the data from the database and store it as a provider therefor I need something like await or so

Answer (score 0):

you can try it so:

```dart
final myReceivedDataProvider = FutureProvider<CustomUserData>((ref) async {
  return CustomUserData.withData(...);
});

class MyPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final data = ref.watch(myReceivedDataProvider);
    
    return data.when(
      data: (CustomUserData data) {
        // TODO
        return Text('$data');
      },
      error: (e, s) {
        return Text('$e, $s');
      },
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks, I will test it. Can I somewhere store this data in a separate  provider to habe this state everywhere in my app ?

Comment: Yes, you can :)